# Update content based on variable value change

Tags: javascript, php

This seems like it should be pretty simple, but I'm trying to update the data based on a variable value change.  When you click the button, I need the variable "filter" to change its value, which will then change the content on the page.  When the value changes, we're making a WP call to retrieve new content.  My problem is, I'm having difficulty figuring out how to update the value using an onclick event with PHP.

```
function filterMedia(filter) {
  const currentURL = window.location.href;
  fetch(currentURL, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({ "filter": filter }),
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

```
<?php
    $filter = "";
                    
    if (isset($_POST['filter'])) {
      switch($_POST['filter']) {
        case "media":
          $filter = "news-article";
          break;
        case "press":
          $filter = "press-release";
          break;
        case "video":
          $filter = "video";
          break;
      }
    }
?>
```

```
<div class="news-filter">
  <div class="filter">
    <button onclick="filterMedia('media')">In The Media</button>
  </div>
  <div class="filter">
    <button onclick="filterMedia('press')">Press Releases</button>
  </div>
  <div class="filter">
    <button onclick="filterMedia('video')">Videos</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't use `$_POST` to get parameters sent as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

PHP `$_POST` is only filled in from url-encoded or multipart/form-data parameters, it doesn't parse JSON content. So send that format:

```
function filterMedia(filter) {
  const currentURL = window.location.href;
  fetch(currentURL, {
    method: "POST",
    body: "filter=" + encodeURIComponent(filter),
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236977/discussion-between-pingeyeg-and-barmar).